# Модуль tensorflow не видит метод get_default_graph

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

Работаю в Jupyter-Lab из дистрибутива Anaconda, запускаю код, получаю ошибку:

```
module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_graph'
```

Код заведомо рабочий (его точно запускали ранее), значит скорее всего у меня что-то неправильно с версиями пакетов.

В своё окружение конды устанавливал Keras версии 2.2.4 и tensorflow версии 1.14.0, также устанавливал tensorflow-gpu версии 1.14.0 (но последний не должен влиять - у меня на машине, на которой я запускаю, нет GPU).

Что могло вызвать эту ошибку? Как её исправить (не правя код)?

Comment: Как её исправить (__не правя код__)? - установите  `keras==2.1.3`

Comment: Установил керас версии 2.1.3, теперь ошибка `ImportError: cannot import name 'DepthwiseConv2D' from 'keras.layers'`. Возможно, потому что `DepthwiseConv2D` добавлен как раз в версии 2.2.4 . Так почему `get_default_graph` не импортировался в 2.2.4 ? Его в этой версии нет ?